# class inherits unrelated defaults for spliterator() from types java.util.Set and java.util.List

Tags: java, java-8, technical-debt

I have class that implements Set and List.  Programs works fine in Java6 and Java7

```
public class SetList<V> implements Set<V>, List<V>
{
  ....
}
```

With Java 8 , this does not compile. Error is

> java: class trials.SetList inherits unrelated defaults for
>   spliterator() from types java.util.Set and java.util.List

java/util/Set.java:394

```
 ...
@Override
default Spliterator<E> spliterator() {
    return Spliterators.spliterator(this, Spliterator.DISTINCT);
}
```

java/util/List.java

```
...
@Override
default Spliterator<E> spliterator() {
    return Spliterators.spliterator(this, Spliterator.ORDERED);
}
```

Does it mean I cannot have class that implement both Set and List in Java 8? (It looks like time has come to pay our technical debts.)

Comment: Provide your own implementation of `spliterator()`.

Comment: How can a class implement both Set and List? They have contraditory contracts. This sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis - thanks , that is probably the _answer_.

Comment: It will fix the compilation problem, but the issue is really what @JBNizet is talking about.

Comment: @ JB Nizet : Thanks.  I guess fixing the real problem is better than the fixing the 'compilation' part.

Comment: You can't _correctly_ implement both `Set` and `List` in _any_ version of Java.

Comment: @ Louis Wasserman : I agree. I am looking at changing the class to two different classes -- SortedSet and UniqueList

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While it is unusual that a class implements both `List` and `Set`, there are some situations, where a `Set` can also support being a somewhat limited `List`.

Personally, I prefer to declare an `asList()` method in these cases, instead of implementing both `List` and `Set` at the same time. Something like this:

```
public class SetList<V> implements Set<V> {
    public List<V> asList(){
        // return a list representation of this Set
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if you already have an existing class, that implements both `List` and `Set`, then the simplest solution for your problem is perhaps to explicitly call one of the super `spliterator()`methods:

```
public class SetList<V> implements Set<V>, List<V> {
    @Override
    public Spliterator<V> spliterator() {
        return List.super.spliterator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

This is [Diamond Problem that occurs with Multiple inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem).

> The "diamond problem" (sometimes referred to as the "deadly diamond of
> death") is an ambiguity that arises when two classes B and C
> inherit from A, and class D inherits from both B and C. If there is a
> method in A that B and C have overridden, and D does not override it,
> then which version of the method does D inherit: that of B, or that of
> C?

In Java , compile error prevents this problem. To resolve this, you should provide your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using multiple underlying Lists and Sets in my `ListSet` class.

Since I happen to already implement the `size()` and `iterator()` methods (Using Guava `Iterators.concat`) the easiest solution was to use the `Spliterators.spliterator()` overload accepting an `Iterator` and size.

```
/**
 * A custom list container that combines a set of unchangeable items with a list of changeable ones.
 * An iterator {@link #iterator()} is available that will iterate first through the unchangeable
 * items and then through the changeable ones. {@link #size()} is the total combined size and
 * {@link #get(int)} can return either an item from the unchangeable list or the changeable one.
 *
 * @param <E>
 */
class ListSet<E> implements List<E>, Set<E> {
    @NonNull
    private final ImmutableList<E> mConstantItemsList;
    @NonNull
    private final ImmutableSet<E> mConstantItemsSet;
    @NonNull
    private final List<E> mVariableItems;

    ListSet(Set<E> constantItems) {
        mConstantItemsSet = ImmutableSet.copyOf(constantItems);
        mConstantItemsList = ImmutableList.copyOf(constantItems);
        mVariableItems = Lists.newArrayList();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return Iterators.concat(mConstantItemsList.iterator(), mVariableItems.iterator());
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mConstantItemsList.size() + mVariableItems.size();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public Spliterator<E> spliterator() {
        return Spliterators.spliterator(iterator(), size(), Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.DISTINCT);
    }
}
```