# Class inheriting same method from two different interfaces and a single default implementation won't compile

Tags: java, interface, default-method

I have stumbled upon a strange issue working with default methods.

Consider this situation:

```
interface A {
    int method();
}
```

```
interface B {
    default int method() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

```
class C implements A, B {
    void anotherMethod() { }
}
```

I would expect class `C` to be fine as-is: it should implement `method`, because that's the contract of both `A` and `B`, and it actually does, because `B` provides a default implementation.

However, the compiler does not agree with me, saying:

`C is not abstract and does not override abstract method method()`

I can totally see the issue in other similar cases, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22746948/3328545), but I can't figure out what's wrong with this code.

Comment: That’s right, when `A` declares the method without default implementation, then you must explicitly implement it in `C`. Your implementation in `C` may simply do `return B.super.method();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be nothing wrong from a syntax perspective, but the question is: does it make sense to have a default method from interface B, override the abstract method of another unrelated interface A?

Imagine the two interfaces represented two different ways to compute a value: one that allows `null` values to be returned, and the other does not. If the default method for the first interface returned `null`, that would violate the contract of the second. And if the compiler allows it to be inherited in class C, then class C is effectively violating one of the implemented interfaces' contract, possibly leading to a bug without the programmer's attention.

Note that if B were a class rather than interface, then there is no issue at compilation, because the issue of "mixed contract" is not present in this case, as there is only one interface.

Comment: I guess I agree with you, although in my case I explicitly wanted to exploit an interface having a method already 'implemented' by the another one to simplify the creation of new classes. Guess I'll just stick to good ol' overrides.